# Joomla layout CSS classes in a view into iFrame

Tags: component, javascript, css, joomla-4.x, view

In the chat component I developed there is a View inside an Iframe in the Main View. The component's CSS works normally, but I can't use the standard Joomla layout classes. The HTML is sent by the component's Javascript into the HTML of a DIV.
Example:

`<i class="icon-clock"></i>`

Component:
https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/tabapapo/

Comment: What is the URL of the iframe?

Comment: src="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_tabapapo&view=tabapapo&layout=messages&tmpl=messages'); ?>"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work the way you expect because you're using `tmpl` URL parameter with value `messages`. What this parameter does is tells is to render the page using the specified template layout. When the given layout doesn't exist, the default (`index`) layout from `system` template is used. It has minimal styling and does not load the icon stylesheets. Changing the `tmpl` parameter value to `component` alone would work with the default Cassiopeia template. But if you expect certain CSS classes to work, you should also load the stylesheets in your view layout so it actually works with all templates. To enable fontawesome, you can use this:

```
$this->document->getWebAssetManager()->useStyle('fontawesome');
```

Another thing to consider is that using classes and allowing HTML in general is probably not the best idea for a live chat. Would be better to use some sort of shortcodes or alternative syntax like Markdown. Or, if you do use HTML, you should at least filter out dangerous tags and attributes. Because currently your component is wide open to XSS attacks.

Comment: Thank you, it worked.
As for XSS attacks, I don't know if there is any risk, my component removes all HTML tags before sending the messages to the database.

Comment: You're wrong. The component does not filter user input before storing, nor does it escape it on display. If it did, inserting an icon with `<i class="icon-clock"></i>` would not work. Now anyone can insert tags with JavaScript event attributes.

Comment: I'm confused. Anyone can write tags in the text box, but before the message is sent the HTML tags are stripped by the stripHtml function in the component's javascript. The <i class="icon-clock"></i> tag is in the component code and is working. To the database goes only encrypted text.

Comment: That part of JS code is currently broken. Also, you mustn't rely on client side code to perform filtering and validation because it can be bypassed with ease. This needs to be done on the server side.

Comment: I published a new version of the component with changes to the form, I hadn't done the XML, now I'm using the renderfield function to create the inputs. Please if you can check if that was it I would be grateful.

Comment: It now errors fatally on PHP 8.

Comment: I already solved it. I put variables in getListQuery() function and it gave incompatibility with the class. I changed the function name.